# First post and late answer review queues always empty?

Tags: discussion, review

I think it's since the "No action needed" buttons were introduced, that there are no posts to review in the queues mentioned in the title.

I'm just wondering, why is that? Before that there was plenty to do.

Comment: Don't forget about the hats.

Comment: There's a hat offered for reviewing posts.

Comment: Those queues have been empty for months now, not just since that button was added.

Comment: @Servy I disagree, they were sometimes empty, but when you hit F5 usually there were like 5-8 posts in each queue on average. It's just since recently, that I see absolutely no post anymore. And the queues were empty again fast as hell. I reviewed 1 or 2, clicked on "Next" and queue was empty again.

Comment: It's because low-rep users can review first post and late answers. Other review tasks require *much* more rep

Comment: It's badly broken, by rep farmers who don't actually review. Lots of other threads on this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pretty clearly, the 'dribble' process has delivered all the old late answers that it is going to deliver. So all we see are new ones. And there seems to be quite a supply of us who watch the queues and respond. You are just unlucky.

Answer (score 0):

Reviewing requires patience.

There is enough to review, but you need to monitor the queues often.

Comment: That is only true for the Close Votes queue and to a limited extent the Suggested Edits queue.  Last night 9K answers showed up in one of the other queues (I think first posts) and they were all gone by this morning.  The other queues are almost always empty.