# Review queues always empty

Tags: support, review

I am not able to review any post although I have enough reputation (more than 1400) on my Stack Overflow account.

However, the review queues always show zero contents.

Up until now I've only reviewed one item. Is something broken?

Comment: Ah okay, so the queues you have access to are simply empty.

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of what you see when you access the [review](http://stackoverflow.com/review/) page?

Comment: The "First Posts" and "Late Answers" queues (which are all you can review before 2000 Rep) are actually empty most of the time, as there are a lot of potential reviewers (anyone with at least 500 Rep). I at least see 0 almost all the time.

Comment: @Duncan - After reopening just vote to close it as a duplicate of [First post and late answer review queues always empty?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/159892/187824)

Comment: @hims056 Ha, didn't realise there was a duplicate. Oh well...

Comment: No issue for me @Duncan

Answer (score 10, accepted):

At your current reputation, you can only see the "Late Answers" and "First Posts" (I believe). These queues are often empty and, even when they're not, a large group of users constantly patrols the queues and will snatch up the opportunity to review.

Once your reputation increases, you'll gain access to some queues that typically have a handful of items in them at any one point. Once you reach 3k, you can drown in all the close reviews you can handle...

[image: review queue]

(*Minimal reputation artfully added in red*)

Comment: Until you get to 3K reputation and see the unimaginable horror of the close vote queue

Comment: [That's our close vote queue!?](http://i.imgur.com/7NDYQLF.gif)

Comment: @Jonathan [that's more like it](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Iam62l.jpg) ;)